# Are there any other Grash like enhanced Groovy shells?

Tags: groovy, groovyshell

Grash seems to be an interesting approach to taking groovy to the next step in terms of connectivity and monitoring of java applications. However, it seems to never have taken off and remained a toy. Has any done something similar, how did it work out ? Are there any other libs like Grash that do "more"?

Answer (score 0):

Grash doesn't appear to be maintained anymore the links in the blog [post](http://www.javanicus.com/blog2/items/161-index.html) introducing it are dead.

However, for monitoring, there are several tools listed [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744900/what-is-the-best-or-most-commonly-used-jmx-console-client) and [here](http://java-source.net/open-source/jmx) for [JMX](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/jmx/) that I think should provide the information you need.

And for interactive Groovy, there is [groovyConsole](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_groovyconsole_the_groovy_swing_console) and [groovyShell](http://docs.groovy-lang.org/latest/html/documentation/#_groovysh_the_groovy_shell).