# JMX batch client?

Tags: jmx, batch-processing

I am looking for a JMX client that can invoke an mbean operation from a batch file. Actually a cron job should invoke an operation via JMX in Weblogic server.

Unfortunately VisualVM does not work in batch mode (or does it?).

So, what do you use as JmX batch client?

Has anybody tried http://wiki.cyclopsgroup.org/jmxterm
? I could not find out what license it's under

[What is the best or most commonly used JMX Console / Client](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1744900/what-is-the-best-or-most-commonly-used-jmx-console-client)

Thx, Juergen

Comment: Does it have to be jmx? You can invoke an mbean with WLST all via a script/cron. Something like https://forums.oracle.com/forums/thread.jspa?messageID=4092361

Answer (score 0):

I faced into the same problem and that's why I wrote simple utility to help me update JMX properties on several machines by running one command. Also, It makes possibility to get their  values by running tool by cron. I wrote post about that http://simpletoad.blogspot.com/2013/06/jmx-batch-updates.html. Plz, share your opinion. There is also code available on github, don't hesitate to fork me