# Active MQ Artemis via jConsole/JMX

Tags: java, jmx, jconsole, activemq-artemis

I am using Artemis 1.3 and I want to monitor it using jConsole (as proposed in [How to monitor Apache Artemis](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162532/how-to-monitor-apache-artemis)).

I am generally able to connect to Artemis, but I have some questions to its usage.
(These questions are mainly questions to the interface `org.apache.activemq.artemis.api.jms.management.JMSQueueControl` as I believe that
these are the methods that will be called via JMX):

1) I can display all messages on a queue by execution a queue's operation "listMessages" with a parameter null.
It will tell me the message's parameters like messageID, priority, whether it's durable, etc.
However, I cannot get the payload of the message. Which command can give me the contents of the message?
[image: Screenshot of jConsole executing listMessages]

2) what is the filter parameter for "listMessages"?
I only get a response when I set it to null, but with every other value I only get an empty result.

3) While reading messages from queues works, I fail to read messages that were sent on a topic.
This is somehow logic due to the way topics work, but I would have hoped that when I call "pause" on a topic, then the messages 
remain until I call "resume". Unfortunately this does not work. Is there another way to see what messages arrive on a topic?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. You can try with `browse()` operation.
2. For filter parameter, you need to specify property-value pair like `JMSPriority=4` -> `listMessages(JMSPriority=4)`
3. No. Until subscriber is durable, messages will not be store for topic.

Comment: thanks for answers 2) and 3)! Concerning 1): where do I find the browse() operation? As you see in the screenshot above, there is no such operation in my case.

Comment: Artemis 1.5.0 provides browse() operation.