# AppDynamics monitoring with AMQ 7.0.1

Tags: jmx, activemq-artemis, jboss-amq

I am using the ActiveMQ extension of AppDynamics. It is good to start. With JMXRemote(enabled in artemis.profile) it is OK. But, I want it from localhost. JMX is enabled by default for localhost for AMQ. AMQ management console use jmx internally and it works without JMXRemote enabled. What service URL jolokia use internally to connect using JMX from localhost? I have tryed with following URL:

> serviceUrl: "service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://:1099/jmxrmi"

Comment: Followup to chat under https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37162532/how-to-monitor-apache-artemis/38456427?noredirect=1#comment87451970_38456427

Comment: @user7610, not sure what you mean by your comment. I have created as new item as you suggested. Now, here you are pointing old one.

Answer (score 0):

The first step is to add a username and password in the etc/users.properties file. For most purposes, it is ok to just 
use the default settings provided out of the box. For this, just uncomment the following line:

```
admin=admin,admin,manager,viewer,Operator, Maintainer, Deployer, Auditor, Administrator, SuperUser
```

Then, you must bypass credential checks on BrokeViewMBean by adding it to the whitelist ACL configuration. You can do so by replacing this line:

```
org.apache.activemq.Broker;getBrokerVersion=bypass
```

with this:

```
org.apache.activemq.Broker=bypass
```

In addition to being the correct way, it also enables several different configuration options (eg: port, listen address, etc) by just changing the file org.apache.karaf.management.cfg on broker's etc directory.

Please keep in mind that JMX access is made through a different JMX connector root in this case: it uses `karaf-root` instead of `jmxrmi`, which was previously used in the older method. It also uses port 1099 by default, instead of 1616.

Therefore, the uri should be

```
service:jmx:rmi:///jndi/rmi://<host>:<port>/karaf-root
```

Comment: thanks for all these details. It seems it is more specific to artemis than it's paid successor jboss amq. I shall try to implement these on Jboss-AMQ. Still now one confusion is there. Access of JMX from remorte machine so easy(just a small change in existing settings). But, even if JMX is enabled by default for localhost, we need to change all these settings and that is also not in base component of artemis, rather in karaf. There should be a easy way to access using JMX from localhost.

Comment: This is for ActiveMQ 5.x or JBoss A-MQ 6. Are you actually asking about ActiveMQ Artemis or Red Hat JBoss AMQ 7?

Comment: The thing is, the AppDynamics extension https://www.appdynamics.com/community/exchange/extension/activemq-monitoring-extension/ is for ActiveMQ 5.x, or A-MQ 6. And AMQ 7 has the management API sufficiently different that the extension is unlikely to work. You may really have to use the generic  https://docs.appdynamics.com/display/PRO43/Monitor+JMX with AMQ 7 until a specific extension for Artemis is developed.